# flexbox css3 LI based menu (nav.treehouse) css formating not working and overflows. In frames ok

Tags: css, flexbox

I am attempting to change from frames to flexbox.  My major problem is I have a complicated css3 driven LI menu. Inside a column I see my commands but they lose all formatting and they overflow.
I am not a programmer but a teacher learning then using what I learn to help others.  What I show here is from my bible note taking system but all the other non-bible educational off line "note-systems" use the same structure.  This totally works fine in frames. But I keep hearing they are no longer a part of html.  This never runs on line.  Its for students to use on their tablet/netbook etc.  It runs in Linux, mac, bsd, windows, android (dont have ipad to test it) in frames.

I do have a webpage where you can see how this works in frames.  www.neocities.loyalstreehouse.net  This page is for helping students with class assignments. Ive shortened the menu as it is very long (A-Z menus with sub-menus)  tried to use a scroll bar but it still over flows and css formatting is lost.

`enter code here`

```
<style type="text/css">
`.row1 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-height: calc(70vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */
}
.row2 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-height: calc(30vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */
  overflow: hidden;
}


.col-1 {
  flex: 0 1 28%;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 0 1 16%;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: ;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;  
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-height: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-3 {
  flex: 0 1 24%;
  background: beige;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-4 {
  flex: 0 1 6%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { margin: 0; }



.flex-fill {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -moz-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.flex-fixed {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -moz-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.lhs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.list-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

nav.treehouse ul
{   padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;}
nav.treehouse li
{   padding: 0px;
    margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;}
nav.treehouse li label
{   padding: 12px;
    margin: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial, Sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16pt;}
nav.treehouse a:hover
{   text-decoration: underline;}
nav.treehouse input
{   position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;}
nav.treehouse input + label + ul
{   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: none;}
nav.treehouse input:checked:not(:disabled) + label + ul
{   display: block;}
nav.treehouse label::before
{   cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;,
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-position: 0 -32px;}
nav.treehouse input:checked + label::before
{   background-position: 0 -16px;}


li.en24-N
{  color: black;
    font-family: arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 24pt;}
    p
{   color: black;
    font-family: arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;}
</style>
</head>
<body>






<section class="row1">
    <div class="col-1" id="file-A">file-A</div>
    <div class="col-1" id="file-B">file-B</div>
    <div class="col-1" id="file-C">file-C</div>
    <nav class="col-2">
    <ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="item-00-01" /><label for="item-00-01" class="green1"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en">Notes</span></label>
    <ul>            
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-01-01" /><label for="item-01-01"  class="green2"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en"> AE-eng </span></label>    
    <ul>    
    <li><a href="AE-eng__loy/_0_AE-eng__idx/AE-eng__indx-A.html" target="index-A" class="green8"> A </a>  
    <a href="AE-eng__loy/_0_AE-eng__idx/AE-eng__indx-B.html" target="index-B" class="green8"> B </a>
    <a href="AE-eng__loy/_0_AE-eng__idx/AE-eng__indx-C.html" target="index-C" class="green8"> C </a>    
    </li></ul>
    </li><li><input type="checkbox" id="item-01-02" /><label for="item-01-02"  class="green2"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en"> AE-tha </span></label>   
    <ul>
    <li><a href="AE-tha__loy/_0_AE-tha__idx/AE-tha__indx-A.html" target="index-A" class="green8"> A </a> 
    <a href="AE-tha__loy/_0_AE-tha__idx/AE-tha__indx-B.html" target="index-B" class="green8"> B </a> 
    <a href="AE-tha__loy/_0_AE-tha__idx/AE-tha__indx-C.html" target="index-C" class="green8"> C </a> 
    </li></ul>
    </li><li><input type="checkbox" id="item-01-03" /><label for="item-01-03"  class="green2"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en"> Inspire </span></label>      
    <ul>    
    <li><a href="AI__loy/_0_AI-eng__idx/AI-eng__indx-A.html" target="index-A" class="green8"> A </a>
    <a href="AI__loy/_0_AI-eng__idx/AI-eng__indx-B.html" target="index-B" class="green8"> B </a>    
    <a href="AI__loy/_0_AI-eng__idx/AI-eng__indx-C.html" target="index-C" class="green8"> C </a>    
    </li></ul>
    </li><li><input type="checkbox" id="item-01-04" /><label for="item-01-04"  class="green3"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en"> Journal </span></label>      
    <ul>
    <li><a href="AJ__loy/_0_AJ-eng__idx/AJ-eng__indx-A.html" target="index-A" class="green8"> A </a> 
     <a href="AJ__loy/_0_AJ-eng__idx/AJ-eng__indx-B.html" target="index-B" class="green8"> B </a> 
     <a href="AJ__loy/_0_AJ-eng__idx/AJ-eng__indx-C.html" target="index-C" class="green8"> C </a> 
     </li></ul>
    </li><li><input type="checkbox" id="item-01-05" /><label for="item-01-05"  class="green3"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en"> Notes </span></label>    
    <ul>
     <li><a href="AN__loy/_0_AN-eng__idx/AN-eng__indx-A.html" target="index-A" class="green8"> A </a> 
     <a href="AN__loy/_0_AN-eng__idx/AN-eng__indx-B.html" target="index-B" class="green8"> B </a> 
     <a href="AN__loy/_0_AN-eng__idx/AN-eng__indx-C.html" target="index-C" class="green8"> C </a> 
     </li></ul>
    </li><li><input type="checkbox" id="item-01-06" /><label for="item-01-06"  class="green3"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en"> Quest </span></label>    
    <ul>
     <li><a href="AQ__loy/0_AQ-eng__idx/AQ-eng__2018__indx-A.html" target="index-A" class="green8"> A </a> 
     <a href="AQ__loy/0_AQ-eng__idx/AQ-eng__2018__indx-B.html" target="index-B" class="green8"> B </a>
     <a href="AQ__loy/0_AQ-eng__idx/AQ-eng__2018__indx-C.html" target="index-C" class="green8"> C </a> 
    </li>
    </ul>       
    <!-- INSERT  MORE A -->
    </li></ul>

   </div>
  </section>

<section class="row2">
    <div class="col-3" id="index-A">index-A</div>
    <div class="col-4" id="menu-A">menu-A</div>
    <div class="col-3" id="index-B">index-B</div>
    <div class="col-4" id="menu-B">menu-B</div>
    <div class="col-3" id="index-C">index-C</div>
    <div class="col-4" id="menu-C">menu-C</div>
    <div class="col-2" id="second-menu-A">secondary-menu</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Your HTML seems to be not valid: the order of closing tags is either messed up or is missing some. This might be the source of issue.

Comment: I figured out that my pure css3 menu has to be in a separate file.  I linked it in with a iframe but this messes up the bottom row in the flexbox setup.  Lobas I did not copy the whole menu inside the post as it makes my post more than 3000 words. I messed up where to cut it. the menu is very big as I use an alphahbet based directory that has sub-menus that are nearly 10,000 links in the reading program.  My bible program has more than 20,000 links.  Thanks for taking a look  sorry I was not careful where I cut down the menu.  The frame version is partly up at loyalstreehouse.neocities.org

Answer (score 0):

I found you can use Iframe in flexbox.  (I thought it was a part of frames so assumed it was  not acceptable code.  But the menu now dislplays formatted.  But still have not figured why if the iframe is in the first row the second flexbox row disappears.  If I put the Iframe in the second row the first row comes back.  The page has two flexbox rows.  Now I am searching on iframne and flexbox to see if anyone else has addressed this.  If you have please respond.  I will post this as another question.